# Помогите поставить запятую.

Tags: словосочетания, пунктуация

"Используются разные цветы в т. ч. фиалки, крокусы, незабудки..." Перед "В том числе" нужна запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используются разные цветы, в т. ч. фиалки, крокусы, незабудки.

Да, запятая нужна, это обособленное дополнение со значением включения.Обороты со значением включения или исключения обычно имеют значение ДОБАВОЧНОГО СООБЩЕНИЯ и обособляются.

Похожий пример: Главную пищу этих птиц составляют змеи, в том числе и ядовитые.

Comment: Спасибо, Вера!